# I have to show an error message whenever a user enters a string that doesn't match any item in the user array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

When I use `else if` to show an error message, it says "wrong username" even when the username is correct but the password is incorrect. Except for the last username in the "user" array.

But when I remove the `else if` it does nothing when a user enters the wrong username.

I think the `for` loop is creating that problem.
Am I using the wrong loop for the wrong purpose? what should I do?

Codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-moser-ybvwb3?file=/src/App.js:1066-1203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, **you shouldn't have your credentials hard coded to the front-end like that.** Anyone could just read the code and get in.

That being said, you need to break the loop when the username is found:

```
if (usernameState === user[i]) {
  if (passwordState === pass[i]) {
    setLoginState(true);
    setMessageState("Login successful.");
  } else if (passwordState === "") {
    setMessageState("Enter password.");
    passwordinput.current.focus();
  } else {
    setMessageState("Wrong password.");
    passwordinput.current.focus();
  }
  break;
}
```

Otherwise you will continue to process each username since no matches were found. I really wouldn't use a `for` loop for this at all. You should do your check for an empty string first, then find if the username is in your array, then if it is check the password. But again **you really shouldn't embed the credentials in your front-end code!**